# Is there a way to disallow a path in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a development and production version of the frontend/API. The production version is in the folder `public/articles/...` and the development version is in `public/articles/development/...`. It contains javascript, css and other assets.

In my Rails routes I have:

```
get 'articles' => 'articles#show'
```

Visiting `production_url/articles/#1` brings me to the api in production, and `development_url/articles/development/#1` brings me to the api in development.

I would like to prevent anyone being able to visit the development version on the production site: `production_url/articles/development/#1`. Is there a way in Rails routes to disallow/reroute someone visiting this url/path?

Comment: Is it `production_url/articles/#1` or `production_url/articles/1`? Big difference!

Comment: Why is it in `public/`?

Comment: Someone else has developed the api front end, which has assets and references to these assets. So it cannot be included in the asset pipeline or else these references would break down. That why it's placed in the public folder. Actually the url is: `production_url/articles/#/1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you "disallow" a route is by not defining it in the first place. Your development versions shouldn't have been defined in production. If you want to write out functionality based in an environment, your best bet is to simply encapsulate the functionality in a block like this:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
    #...
end
```

That said, this form of having specific "Development" and "Production" versions of services, each deployed to your Development and Production sites seems... unconventional, at best.